# passing argument in xlwings RunPython VBA function

Tags: python-3.x, vba, xlwings

I am getting some data from excel sheets using python. I'm using xlwings to accomplish this. I am trying to pass the path to the current workbook to my file, where it can use it to find the Excel book. I cannot use xlwings UDF's.

Here's my VBA code:

```
Sub Button1_Click()

    RunPython ("import exceltest; exceltest.excelTest('" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & "')")

End Sub
```

Here's my exceltest.py Python code:

```
def excelTest(path_of_file):
    print (path_of_file)
```

Here's the error I'm getting:

---

### Error

```
  File "<string>", line 1

SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The path `ThisWorkbook.FullName` probably has a special slash character in it that Python is interpreting as something else. What characters follow the slashes in the path?

Comment: @MBB70 when I run `Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.FullName` it outputs `C:\Users\gageb\Desktop\test.xlsm`

Comment: Your error is telling you that there is a problem at character 2-3...so I would suspect `\U`...Can you hard code the workbook path, or will it vary? If you can, try the answer I suggested. `r'''C:\Users\gageb\Desktop\test.xlsm'''`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the full path of your workbook (the actual path instead of `ThisWorkbook.FullName` and structure it like this `r'''myfullpath\mysubfolder\myExcelfile'''`

Comment: Yes, this would work, but this macro will be running on an Excel template, I need to know where the user has saved the file.

Comment: Try ... `myWBName = "r'''" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & "'''"` then `RunPython ("import exceltest; exceltest.excelTest('" & myWBName & "')")`

Answer (score 0):

I needed to use `RunPython ("import exceltest; exceltest.excelTest(r'" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & "')")`

Comment: It would be good if you could tell me if the method I suggested worked also. I don't have xlwings installed. If the only difference between your answer and mine is slightly different quote structure, I'd like to know.

Comment: "Any help would be greatly appreciated!"

Comment: "Great appreciation" would be minimally expressed with at the very least an upvote of my comments and/or answer. It would take you less than a second to do this. I don't need a pat on the back here, but the fact is that my insight led you directly to your answer. It doesn't seem right for you to treat this community like an answer-mill, turning your back once you have what you need. I'm new too, but it's clear already to me that there is a culture of mutual respect here.